# Convert sequence of System.Windows.Forms.Keys to a Char

Tags: .net, winforms, keyboard, char, keycode

Is there a way to convert a sequence of keystrokes represented by the Keys enum (i.e. `System.Windows.Forms.Keys`) in a Char. For example: `Keys.Oem4` and then `Keys.A` yields the char `á`. It must exist somewhere in the WinAPI, because Windows does that for me, when I press keys inside a text-box... I just don't know where. Please help! thanks.

**EDIT:**

What I want is to record the user input keys, and later translate the sequence of keys to characters, without the user having to type everything again, something like a macro.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way to do this is to first convent the `Key` value into a Virtual Key code.  This is done via [KeyInterop.VirtualKeyFromKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyinterop.virtualkeyfromkey.aspx).  You can then PInvoke into the [MapVirtualKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646306(VS.85).aspx) function to convert the key into a char.

Comment: No good.  Notice original poster said:  "i.e. System.Windows.Forms.Keys" which implies he's using winforms.  KeyInterop requires WPF.  From the docs:  Converts a WPF Key into a Win32 Virtual-Key.   How can we do this with winform keys?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be internal to Windows. The best info I can find is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/using-keyboard-input

Basically the window receives a `WM_CHAR` message after `TranslateMessage` is called on the `WM_KEYDOWN` etc. messages received in the message loop. The `WM_CHAR` message then contains the character you want.